# You don't have Permission to modify Internal Hyper-V network adapter

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone

I am using win 8.1 and visual studio 2013 update 2. Just a beginner to Window Phone, Writing my first program and unable to run the emulator. I had search this error on Google and try all the solution but still my problems are not solved.
[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Are you logged on as an Administrator? If that doesn't work/you already are, try this: http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/ed72010c-321c-4667-97b2-3ff1540e7f87/action?threadDisplayName=win-phone-8-you-dont-have-permission-to-modify-internal-hyperv-internal-network-adaptor-required&forum=wptools

Comment: Also try running the program as an administrator depending on your security settings.